# How could pass an object function by reference to another library funcion that needs a funcion with the same args and the same returns

Tags: c++

I have an example of my real problem. I use a C library that have a function that needs a pointer fucntions to be called laters. But I need that call would be an object function, but I cant to do this:

```
class MyClass{
  static int numberObjects; 
  //...
public:
  MyClass(int num){
    numberObjects++;
    //...
  }
  void myFunction(int num){
    //...
  } 
};
int MyClass::numberObjects = 0;


void functionExtern(int number){
  //...
}

void functionLibrary(void (* f)(int)){
  //...
  int arg;
  f(arg);
}

typedef void (MyClass::* pointerMyClassFunction)(int x);
typedef void (* functionPattern)(int x);
```

This works fine:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
  MyClass class1(10);
  MyClass class2(20);
   
    
  class1.myFunction(100);
  class2.myFunction(200);
    
    
  functionExtern(4);
  functionLibrary(functionExtern);

}
```

And when I try to do this, I have an error:

```
functionLibrary(class1.myFunction);
functionLibrary(&class2.myFunction);
```

I tryed this too, but it is not work:

```
functionLibrary((functionPattern)(class1.*(MyClass::myFunction)));
```

This code is an simplification of the real problem. The library is a TIRTOS library to create tasks in a RTOS of Texas Instruments. It is need a function where is the task (thread), but all is management by objects. Then when you create a new object this could create a new task and so on. Then when you call to Task_Construct (functionLibrary that needs a pointer function by argument) this need a pointer function but I would like to pass an object function with own task (thread).
The arguments are:
taskStruct, (Data structure for the thread)
pointerFunction, (callback for the thread)
taskParams, (another data structure for config the thread)
errorBlock, (is another structure for register errors when you wants to manage them)
This Task_Construct is equivalent to my functionLibrary example, where its prototype is next:

```
#define Task_construct ti_sysbios_knl_Task_construct

void ti_sysbios_knl_Task_construct(ti_sysbios_knl_Task_Struct *__obj, ti_sysbios_knl_Task_FuncPtr fxn, const ti_sysbios_knl_Task_Params *__paramsPtr, xdc_runtime_Error_Block *__eb )
```

The ti_sysbios_knl_Task_FuncPtr fxn is the equivalent to my "void (* f)(int)" argument of functionLibrary. Its prototype is next:

```
typedef xdc_Void (*ti_sysbios_knl_Task_FuncPtr)(xdc_UArg, xdc_UArg);
```

And args:

```
#define xdc_Void        void
typedef uintptr_t       xdc_UArg;
typedef unsigned int    uintptr_t;
```

I tryed to simplify this, in essence I have a "C" function named "functionLibrary" (Task_construc) who need an a "C pointer function" (void (*f)(int)) that is equivalent to typedef xdc_Void (*ti_sysbios_knl_Task_FuncPtr)(xdc_UArg, xdc_UArg)
But if I create an object with this type of functios and I try to pass this to the function I have an error, because I don't know how to change this:

```
void MyClass::myFunction(int)
```

for this:

```
void functionExtern(int)
```

Therefore I could pass &functionExtern but I couldnt pass &myObject.myFunction

Comment: A pointer to a member function is very different to a pointer to a non-member function, and they are not compatible with each other. Unless you can change the function signature of `functionLibrary` it's not possible.

Comment: This is my problem, that we cant change the functionLibrary because is a library of the RTOS that I use and it is used in another programs.

Comment: Callback interfaces usually include at least one parameter for arbitrary data in the callback. What are the actual prototypes?

Comment: This is the function:
    Task_construct(&taskStruct, (Task_FuncPtr)pTask, &taskParams, NULL);
The definitios are the nexts:
    #define Task_FuncPtr ti_sysbios_knl_Task_FuncPtr
    /* FuncPtr */
    typedef xdc_Void (*ti_sysbios_knl_Task_FuncPtr)(xdc_UArg, xdc_UArg);

Comment: What is `taskParams`? What is the last argument (the `NULL` pointer) used for? Please [edit] you question to include information about the actual function you need to call, and also add a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a member function an object is required, but your C function allows you to pass an `int`, rather than `void*` which you could use to pass the pointer to the object. Hence, you need to use that `int` as an index into a global array of pointers to your objects to locate the object:

```
MyClass* objects[2];

void callback(int idx) {
    objects[idx]->myFunction(idx);
}

int main() {
    MyClass a(1);
    MyClass b(2);

    objects[0] = &a;
    objects[1] = &b;

    functionLibrary(callback, 0);
    functionLibrary(callback, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching it seems that the `ti_sysbios_knl_Task_Param` Structure have two members named `arg0` and `arg1`, which could be assumed are the first and second argument to the task function.

You could initialize one of these members to be a pointer to the object.

Then create a plain non-member (or `static` member) function which takes the corresponding argument, cast it to a pointer to your class, and use it to call the member function.

Perhaps something like this:

```
void task_function_wrapper(xdc_UArg arg0, xdc_UArg /* unused */)
{
    MyClass* object = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(arg0);
    object->myFunction();
}

...

MyClass class1(10);

Task_Params params = { };  // Default initialize structure, might need some external call to initialize properly
params.arg0 = &class1;

Task_construct(&taskStruct, &task_function_wrapper, &params, 0);
```